# Passing data from TextField to webpage

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have a model in Django with a `TextField`. I want to pass the info from that `TextField` onto a webpage through

```
return render(request, 'index.html', {
    'textFieldValue': textFieldValue,
    'context': RequestContext(request),
})
```

The problem I'm having is that since the `TextField` can contain new lines, when it's passed onto my webpage by doing:

```
var textFieldValue = "{{ textFieldValue }}";
```

It becomes:

```
var textFieldValue = "Testing string is this. 
New line abcde
Second new lineabcde";
```

Which will return an error due to the fact that there are several lines in the `TextField` and thus breaking the JavaScript var templates.. Is there a way to fix this? Would I need to split the string into an array of each line, then pass that into my webpage, and have a function to parse through that?

I also tried:

```
var textFieldValue = "{{ textFieldValue|safe }}";
```

But it's the same thing.

I want to do this because I want to paste this into a `textarea` on my page, which looks like what the `TextField` is supposed to show in Django admin.

I imagine that there will be problems in the future with symbols like `"`, or `'` quotations, and `@#` etc.

What would be the best way for me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Django's built in `escapejs` filter (docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#escapejs)):

```
{{ value|escapejs }}
```

> e.g, If value is `"testing\r\njavascript \'string" <b>escaping</b>"`, the output will be `"testing\\u000D\\u000Ajavascript \\u0027string\\u0022 \\u003Cb\\u003Eescaping\\u003C/b\\u003E"`.

**Note**: This does not make the string safe for use in HTML, but does protect you from syntax errors when using templates to generate JavaScript/JSON.

Comment: Oh my god. Thank you so much! I was thinking there should be something like this built in! Edit: What I also want to do is that the user can edit what is in the `textarea`, then that text area will be sent back to django to be saved inside the database. How would I make it safe to be sent back?

Comment: It may be better to open a new question as far as how to safely send the data back- you can provide more details on how you wish to do that (e.g, via AJAX, or a regular form POST submit, etc).